# Evaluate sum of integral numerically with Matlab using for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate the following type of problem with Matlab.

[image]

where the summation is taken over `wn` which is a vector, and the variable of integration is `wPrime`. `w`, `wn` and `Ri` are given vectors.

What I've tried is the following: using two `for`-loops.

```
integral = zeros(size(wn));
sumF = zeros(size(w));

for j = 1:length(w);
    for k = 1:length(wn);
        integral(k) = trapz(wPrime,1./(w(j)-1i*wn(k)-wPrime));
    end
    sumF(j) = sum(integral.*wn./sqrt(Ri));
end
```

but I've understood that for loops are very slow in Matlab, so I´m wondering if there is a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Since you have a sum of an integral, it will be hard not to have _some_ for loop. The question is - is the current implementation too slow for you?

Comment: Actually [MATLAB is no longer slow at for loops](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/). So if speedups are your only goal, expect limited results.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - I "kinda knew" that things had changed, but had not come across that post. Very nice. Do you know from what version of Matlab onwards this is true?

Comment: @Floris JIT was introduced some years ago in version 6.5.

Comment: @Floris yes, my current implementation is quite slow and since I've heard that Matlab is slow at for loops i thought that i might be some clever way to avoid it.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks, thats good to know. I guess I'll just have to wait it out then.